# How to bring Animation to front: bringToFront and zAdjustment/Z-ordering

Tags: android, animation, z-order

I have a LinearLayout with two views in it, next to each other. When a view is tapped upon, it animates to full screen. This goes fine for the view on the right, but it fails for the left view:

**I am unable to animate the left view on top of the right view**

Without corrupting my layout with bringToFront(). Adjusting the Z-order of my animation does not seem to work.

Not a solution: The problem is gone when I use "brintToFront()" on the left view, but this causes my layout to be completely corrupted afterwards, and there is no brintToBack() function or whatsoever. => brintToFront = not a good solution?

Adjusting the Z-order of my animation does not seem to work (does not change anything).

```
scaleAnimation.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
translateAnimation.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
set.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
set.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
set.setZAdjustment(AnimationSet.ZORDER_TOP);
myFrameLayout.startAnimation(set);
```

Why does Z-ordering not work as expected?

Comment: No answers? Anything to point me into the right direction?

Comment: I don't have an fix, but I've seen elsewhere that Animation's ZAdjustment only has effect on window animations, despite this not being documented.

Comment: This seems like such a basic oversight, and I'm struggling so hard with this right now. I am so disgusted with this animation package. It's been nothing but a struggle the entire way, and I'm totally pissed. Shit!

Comment: yes. let me know if you find an answer though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be possible if you extend LinearLayout and override the following method:

```
getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i)
```

To make sure layout uses your function you need to call setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true)

See [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildDrawingOrder%28int,%20int%29%20ViewGroup) javadoc

Answer (score 3):

For your z reordering will apply you gonna need to request a new layout on the view, but try doing it before starting your animation:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
// init animation ...
scaledView.bringToFront();
scaledView.requestLayout();
myFrameLayout.startAnimation(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no good answer to this.

I am now animating everything else on the screen too, so if view 1 has to grow larger on top of view 2 than I animate view 2 also, in such a way that it looks like view 1 is growing on top of view 2, while actually view 2 is getting smaller while view 1 is getting larger.

Quite a lot of work and a bad solution, but I guess the only solution.